# Powershell Binary Module : The specified module ' ' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am facing error while deploying binary command let to one of specified directory.
I added the path to `$env:PSModulePath`.

e.g. 
The path is :

```
C:\Program Files\Link 2016\Server\CompanyName.Commandlets\
```

and binary module is :

```
CompanyName.Commandlets.dll
```

But upon Import-Module, it says.

```
Import-Module : The specified module ' ' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (CompanyName.Commandlets:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I followed all the conventions and named them as well formed. Am I missing something? which was is called as 'valid module file'. Did it meant by psd1 or psm1 files. What do I need to write in those files if so.

**Edit:** **(Commandlet Code)**

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

namespace PowershellCommandlet
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Initialize, "OfflineParameterAccess")]
    public class InitializeOfflineParameterAccess : PSCmdlet
    {
        public InitializeOfflineParameterAccess()
        {

```
    }

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {

    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {

    }
}
```

}

And Path where commandlet placed on disk.

[image]

$env:PSModulePath shows the path which is including the above path

[image]

Comment: If it is the dll you wish to load, then why use `IMport-Module`? In this case you should use `Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Link 2016\Server\CompanyName.Commandlets\CompanyName.Commandlets.dll"` or use the `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()` syntax

Comment: No no. The path get'S longer. I want standard way to load modules. There are lots of other modules as well. They also have different paths and paths are much longer.
These modules would be installed in standard way. So , I want user to use Import-Module the way user use standard Azure or windows modules to interact.

Comment: @Usman Create a Module Manifest for it (`New-ModuleManifest`, please review the help/docs for that function)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is it necessary? Docs: "*PowerShell will treat a single cmdlet assembly as a module [..] with no additional effort on the part of the developer. [..] If necessary, create the rest of your solution [..] and describe them with a module manifest. [..] As stated previously however, PowerShell can treat a binary cmdlet like a module with no additional effort. As such, a module manifest is useful mainly for combining multiple files into a single package...*" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-binary-module

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : Even after creating module manifest file having extension .psd1, it says the same. (i.e. The specified module ' ' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.)  I can see .psd1 file created under the same directory where commandlet module lives. 
I created module manifest with the commandlet New-ModuleManifest -Path "C:\Program Files\Link 2016\Server\CompanyName.Commandlets\CompanyName.Commandlets.psd"

Comment: _"I followed all the conventions and named them as well formed"_  Are you sure?  Can you create minimal module with a dummy cmdlet defined that loads ok?  If, as you say, your module is valid, then calling `Import-Module` on it should work - I've written many binary modules that load like that (and via autoload).

Comment: Yes, I created just a dummy module. which is just having dummy class and standard override methods coming from PSCmdlet. Deployed it on the location watchabel by $PSModulePath and I double checked the path.

Comment: @Usman, did it work?  If so, what is different about the failing one?  Perhaps you can add the additional functionality piece-by-piece to your dummy module until it fails.

Comment: I observed that i am using Powershell Version 5 as Major. At current state the way I displayed the $env:PSModulePath and directory structure above, Those commandlets enclosed in dummy module and in other real module automatically loaded. But Import-Module get's failed even on dummy module. and says the same thing like no valid module file found....
I think , I am safe somehow because of Powershell 5 > 3, which can watch all modules at $PSModulePath and automatically loads those modules.